# Entry Point Not Found on qgis_core.dll

Tags: qgis

I would like to know how to set it up correctly in Visual Studio on a Windows system to be able to use the QGIS C++ libraries. I tried a few things, but the running result of my project is always that the `Entry Point Not Found` on `qgis_core.dll`, which is a bit of a pain for me.

The relevant Debug output is:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC24B2F35D (ntdll.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
The thread 0x4350 has exited with code -1073741511 (0xc0000139).
The thread 0x3b18 has exited with code -1073741511 (0xc0000139).
The program '[8244] test.exe' has exited with code -1073741511 (0xc0000139) 'Entry Point Not Found'.
```

Also, would it be faster to use the C++ version of the QGIS library compared to the Python version?

Comment: This usually means your have misnamed or the compiler is misnaming a function call to a DLL /or/ you are using a version of DLL during linking that is different than the DLL used during runtime. That is, the function's excepted entry point location in memory is actually located at a different location or missing completely. Check your DLL versions.

Comment: Thank you for your warm comment! I confirm that my QGIS DLL is consistent with the lib version. The problem may be that the QGIS dependency library is inconsistent with the DLL version of QGIS, such as the error message that always appears is like `zip_strerror`, `xmlNanoHTTPCleanup`. I suspect that the former is the problem of the libzip version, but I am not sure yet. And also it's a problem for me to know the correct version of dependency libs (all libs I am using are got from osgeo4w setup)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scrutinizing all of the Visual Studio's output logs for the issue today, I eventually found that this was not related to the DLLs downloaded by OSGeo4W Setup, but to the DLLs of the same name in other directories where the environment variables had been set.

There have been `zip.dll` and `libxml2.dll` in the bin directory of QGIS, but at the same time, there is `zip.dll` in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin` directory and there is `libxml2.dll` in `C:\Apache24\bin` directory. When running the generated `QtWidgetsApplication1.exe` file, VS first uses these DLLs instead of the DLLs in the `D:\QGIS320\bin` directory which are under the `PATH` environment variable. After simply pasting these two DLLs from the `D:\QGIS320\bin` directory into the same directory of the generated `QtWidgetsApplication1.exe`, the program can just run normally!

Then I simply added a map canvas to the widget and loaded a vector layer. And the result is as shown below.

[image: the added vector layer widget]

It is really a bit of a twist for me to find this problem and fix it. While this is an easy start, for me it is a big step towards using QGIS's C++ version of the API.